# How to plot the 4-D data outputted from scipy.brute() method?

Tags: python, optimization, plot

I am trying to optimize a certain equation that has 3 different variables. Since, I needed the global minimum I am using the scipy.brute() method to find the minimum.

What I now need to do is take the output from that, and create a 4-D graph (probably using color) of all the possible solutions.

The problem is I can't use the regular scatter plots because I have a data point at every integer point.

Also color plot which is my chosen form of graphing, only works on 3-D data.

```py
def objFunc(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] + x[2] #not actual objective

def optim():
    range = (slice(5, 40, 1),) * 3
    result = brute(objFunc, range, full_output=True, finish=None)
    return result
```

The output looks like this:

```
(array([16., 11., 17.]),
 -14.264000000000266,
 array([[[[ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          [ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          [ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          ...,
          [ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          [ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          [ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5]],

         [[ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          ...,
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6]],

         [[ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          ...,
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7]],

         ...,

         [[37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          ...,
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37]],

         [[38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          ...,
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38]],

         [[39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39],
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39],
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39],
          ...,
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39],
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39],
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39]]],


        [[[ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          ...,
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39]],

         [[ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          ...,
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39]],

         [[ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          ...,
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39]],

         ...,

         [[ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          ...,
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39]],

         [[ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          ...,
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39]],

         [[ 5,  5,  5, ...,  5,  5,  5],
          [ 6,  6,  6, ...,  6,  6,  6],
          [ 7,  7,  7, ...,  7,  7,  7],
          ...,
          [37, 37, 37, ..., 37, 37, 37],
          [38, 38, 38, ..., 38, 38, 38],
          [39, 39, 39, ..., 39, 39, 39]]],


        [[[ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          ...,
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39]],

         [[ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          ...,
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39]],

         [[ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          ...,
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39]],

         ...,

         [[ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          ...,
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39]],

         [[ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          ...,
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39]],

         [[ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          ...,
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39],
          [ 5,  6,  7, ..., 37, 38, 39]]]]),
 array([[[ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00, ...,  0.0000e+00,
           0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00],
         [-1.8646e+00, -3.9202e+00, -4.0626e+00, ..., -1.2946e+00,
          -1.7752e+00, -2.1930e+00],
         [-4.3552e+00, -4.0626e+00, -4.9642e+00, ..., -1.7610e+00,
          -5.3600e-02,  2.6060e-01],
         ...,
         [-1.0168e+00,  1.2460e-01, -9.4820e-01, ...,  2.4376e+00,
           2.7144e+00,  4.7294e+00],
         [-8.7720e-01, -3.9600e-01,  7.5920e-01, ...,  2.7144e+00,
           4.6094e+00,  4.7240e+00],
         [-4.6200e-01, -8.1380e-01,  1.0734e+00, ...,  4.7294e+00,
           4.7240e+00,  4.3872e+00]],

        [[ 1.8646e+00,  3.9202e+00,  4.0626e+00, ...,  1.2946e+00,
           1.7752e+00,  2.1930e+00],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00, ...,  0.0000e+00,
           0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00],
         [-3.9826e+00, -4.7238e+00, -7.4158e+00, ...,  4.3906e+00,
           2.7800e+00,  8.0380e-01],
         ...,
         [ 1.2460e-01,  1.7028e+00,  3.6512e+00, ...,  2.2730e+00,
           1.5168e+00,  9.2340e-01],
         [-3.9600e-01,  2.3934e+00,  2.4206e+00, ...,  1.5168e+00,
           9.2340e-01,  1.5756e+00],
         [-8.1380e-01,  1.5208e+00,  1.3440e-01, ...,  9.2340e-01,
           1.5756e+00,  2.8896e+00]],

        [[ 4.3552e+00,  4.0626e+00,  4.9642e+00, ...,  1.7610e+00,
           5.3600e-02, -2.6060e-01],
         [ 3.9826e+00,  4.7238e+00,  7.4158e+00, ..., -4.3906e+00,
          -2.7800e+00, -8.0380e-01],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00, ...,  0.0000e+00,
           0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00],
         ...,
         [-9.4820e-01,  3.2012e+00,  2.3234e+00, ...,  1.8586e+00,
           3.1328e+00,  3.3862e+00],
         [ 7.5920e-01,  1.9706e+00,  1.8436e+00, ...,  3.0428e+00,
           3.3862e+00,  3.5442e+00],
         [ 1.0734e+00, -5.6000e-03,  4.0352e+00, ...,  3.3862e+00,
           3.5442e+00,  2.6238e+00]],

        ...,

        [[ 1.0168e+00, -1.2460e-01,  9.4820e-01, ..., -2.4376e+00,
          -2.7144e+00, -4.7294e+00],
         [-1.2460e-01, -1.7028e+00, -3.6512e+00, ..., -2.2730e+00,
          -1.5168e+00, -9.2340e-01],
         [ 9.4820e-01, -3.2012e+00, -2.3234e+00, ..., -1.8586e+00,
          -3.1328e+00, -3.3862e+00],
         ...,
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00, ...,  0.0000e+00,
           0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00],
         [ 6.6600e-01,  1.2574e+00,  1.1392e+00, ...,  5.3169e+00,
           3.6745e+00,  5.9975e+00],
         [ 2.7666e+00,  6.2400e-01,  1.4826e+00, ...,  3.7183e+00,
           5.9975e+00,  6.0069e+00]],

        [[ 8.7720e-01,  3.9600e-01, -7.5920e-01, ..., -2.7144e+00,
          -4.6094e+00, -4.7240e+00],
         [ 3.9600e-01, -2.3934e+00, -2.4206e+00, ..., -1.5168e+00,
          -9.2340e-01, -1.5756e+00],
         [-7.5920e-01, -1.9706e+00, -1.8436e+00, ..., -3.0428e+00,
          -3.3862e+00, -3.5442e+00],
         ...,
         [-6.6600e-01, -1.2574e+00, -1.1392e+00, ..., -5.3169e+00,
          -3.6745e+00, -5.9975e+00],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00, ...,  0.0000e+00,
           0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00],
         [ 2.6952e+00,  7.3620e-01,  2.1606e+00, ...,  5.9975e+00,
           6.2250e+00,  6.0576e+00]],

        [[ 4.6200e-01,  8.1380e-01, -1.0734e+00, ..., -4.7294e+00,
          -4.7240e+00, -4.3872e+00],
         [ 8.1380e-01, -1.5208e+00, -1.3440e-01, ..., -9.2340e-01,
          -1.5756e+00, -2.8896e+00],
         [-1.0734e+00,  5.6000e-03, -4.0352e+00, ..., -3.3862e+00,
          -3.5442e+00, -2.6238e+00],
         ...,
         [-2.7666e+00, -6.2400e-01, -1.4826e+00, ..., -3.7183e+00,
          -5.9975e+00, -6.0069e+00],
         [-2.6952e+00, -7.3620e-01, -2.1606e+00, ..., -5.9975e+00,
          -6.2250e+00, -6.0576e+00],
         [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00, ...,  0.0000e+00,
           0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00]]]))
```

Which isn't something that I can easily graph